# Getting sequence of associated Product - IBM

Tags: javabeans, websphere-commerce

I want to get 'Rank' value from MASSOCCECE table, since past 2 days I have been searching a lot to get this value but failed I tried 'ProductDatBean',  'RelatedProductDataBean' but couldn't figure out how to get the value of 'rank'.

I have four products as cross-sell of a product and I want to sort them on the basis of 'rank'.

It would be a great help if anyone could tell me how to get this value besides using customized bean.

**EDIT:** For more clarity, adding my code

```
  <wcbase:useBean id="g_mA" classname="com.ibm.commerce.catalog.beans.ProductDataBean" >
        <c:set target="${g_mA}" property="productID" value="${catentry_ID}" />
        </wcbase:useBean>

 <c:set var="g_associatedProducts" value="${g_mA.productCrossSells}" scope="request"/>

 <c:forEach var="associatedProducts" items="${g_associatedProducts}" varStatus="status">
 ${associatedProducts.rank}
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: have you triedRelatedCatalogEntryAccessBean 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.api.doc/com/ibm/commerce/catalog/objects/RelatedCatalogEntryAccessBean.html?lang=en

Comment: @AbedYaseen Yes I saw that and many other posts and tried too but I got blank when I used, RelatedProductDataBean or RelatedCatalogEntryAccessBean's objects.... i think i might be mistaking something, as i am new in  IBM WCS world , would you please tell me how to get this value using aforementioned beans by refrencing them from ProductBean? my ProductBean's object is 'productAssociations'.... i would really be greatful.

Comment: Can you post a sample of code you are trying and the contents of the table you are trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

Got the value, thanks everyone for responses.

I was doing the right thing (${associatedProducts.rank}) for getting this value but I was misguided a little , They were items that were associated and I was informed that they were Products, so getting blank while implementing this logic for Item. Used ItemBean now everything is working fine.